# MPAndroidChart - Horizontal Bar using CombinedChart

Tags: android, charts, mpandroidchart

I am quite new using MPAndroidChart. I want to create a CombinedChart that uses lines and HorizontalBars (instead of VerticalBars), e.g.:

[image]

How can I do this?

Note: Sorry for my lack of creativity creating an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately horizontal bars are **not yet supported** to be combined with any other form of data representation (like lines, scatter, ...).
Such a thing only works with "vertical" data at this point.

Comment: I love your product. I really think is great. Could you consider adding this functionality, I would love it much more!